# Implicit GetResult for nested classes in Slick

Tags: scala, slick

From what I've read, there is a way to work with nested classes to solve the problem of tables with more than 22 fields. It looks like this (with a simple table):

```
case class UserRow(id:Int, address1:Address, address2:Address)
case class Address(street:String,city:String)

class User(tag:Tag) extends Table[UserRow](tag, "User"){
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def street1 = column[String]("STREET1")
  def city1 = column[String]("CITY1")
  def street2 = column[String]("STREET2")
  def city2 = column[String]("CITY2")
  def * = (id, address1, address2) <> (UserRow.tupled, UserRow.unapply)
  def address1 = (street1, city1) <> (Address.tupled, Address.unapply)
  def address2 = (street2, city2) <> (Address.tupled, Address.unapply)
}
```

What I've realized is that plain SQL - which requires implicit values - doesn't work with this solution or at least I haven't been able to make it works.

I thought I could define the implicit values in the same way as the nested classes, like this:

```
implicit val getAddressResult = GetResult(r => Address(r.<<, r.<<))
implicit val getUserResult = GetResult(r => UserRow(r.<<, r.<<, r.<<))
```

But it doesn't work. It compiles but when running, it says that the user table is not found.

I'm very new in Scala and Slick so I could have misunderstood some information or have some wrong concepts. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

This is what I'm doing in the test:

```
user.ddl.create
user += UserRow(0, Address("s11", "c11"), Address("s12", "c12"))
user += UserRow(1, Address("s21", "c21"), Address("s22", "c22"))
user += UserRow(2, Address("s31", "c31"), Address("s32", "c32"))
println(user.list)
val sqlPlain = sql"SELECT * FROM user".as[UserRow]
println(sqlPlain)
println(sqlPlain.list)
```

All of it works until the last sentence where I get the error "Table "USER" not found". Also the exact same test works perfect for a non nested case class.

**UPDATE 2**

As **cvogt** has correctly indicated to me, I was misunderstanding the error reported and it wasn't related to the implicit GetResult values. His answer is correct as well as my first approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the PositionedResult r to the corresponding GetResult objects:

```
implicit val getAddressResult = GetResult(r => Address(r.<<, r.<<))
implicit val getUserResult =
  GetResult(r => UserRow(r.<<, getAddressResult(r), getAddressResult(r)))
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. It seems that every type must be explicit:

"getUserResult is not applicable here because it comes after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type"

Comment: Fixed the Answer. Implicits got in the way. Is that working?  This may help understanding: https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/3.0.0-M1/src/main/scala/scala/slick/jdbc/GetResult.fm

Comment: I tried that yesterday too, but although it compiles, when I runs it, it says the same "Table "USER" not found. And I have checked that the table exists because in the very previous sentences I've inserted and listed the values inserted. If it helps, I'll write as an update what I'm doing in the test.

Comment: Table does not exist has nothing to do with GetResult. You either have a typo, a problem with character case or some other config problem

Comment: You were right. And surprisingly my first approach was correct too. What I was doing wrong is writing the name of the table in lower-case in the class definition (`(tag, "user"){` instead of this `(tag, "USER"){`). Why does it matter? wasn't SQL case-insensitive?

Comment: not case insensitive, it just normalizes the case (standard and most dbs to upper, postgres to lower) when you don't quote. Check your dbs manual